# need sequence as A1 A2 in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Dear all, 
  Using sequence we can insert a sequence of integers in postgers 
like that I just want to insert A1 and A2 , 
Is this possible to do this in a straight forward manner , or otherwise do need to write a  function ?

Please let me know the easiest way of doing this 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Sample schema?  Anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `create table test ( a text );`

```
CREATE TABLE
```

- `insert into test(a) select 'A'||generate_series(1,4)::text;`

```
INSERT 0 4
```

- `select * from test;`

```
 a  
----
 A1
 A2
 A3
 A4
(4 rows)
```